# FrameLayout inside Scroll view

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-scrollview, android-framelayout

I have a very big problem. I have a 60 images (3 columns and 20 rows) that are added into FrameLayout. But there is a problem. I want to scroll those images by ScrollView. So i added Scroll view, and inside it I add FrameLayout. But this scrollview doesn't work (it doesn't scroll). Every image ig fit good but the one problem is it doesn't srcoll. Please help me.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame1"/>
</ScrollView>
```

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x/3;
int height = size.y/3;
iparams =  new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,  width);

for (int y = 0; y < 20;  y++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        final ImageView car = new ImageView(SecondActivity.this);
        car.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_0);
        car.setLayoutParams(iparams);
        car.setId(i+3*y);
        car.setY(y * width);
        car.setX(i * width);
        frameLayout.addView(car);

    }
}
```

Comment: why don't use recyclerview with grid layout manager?

Comment: have you tried `NestedScrollView`? can you also share Resulting view's screenshot?

Comment: the functionality you want can be easily achieved using GridLayoutManager and RecyclerVIew.
please refer to https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html

Comment: try adding frameLayout.onLayout() after your for

Comment: @Sam smooth scrolling, I m a bit confuse as I m unable to figure out the output

Comment: the classes are:                                                                                      
private FrameLayout.LayoutParams iparams;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

Comment: But is it posibble to add loop in  recycler view and gridLayoutMenager?

Comment: Yea, it is. possible.. Make a custom adapter that takes an array of drawable if it is static image or pass url if dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is better to use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager